# Showing that the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sin(\frac {n \pi}{9})$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sin(\frac {i \pi}{9})$ diverges. I just finished a chapter covering the comparison tests, root test, and ratio test. It seems that the comparison text would be appropriate and that I should compare my series to $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {1} {i}$ but I am unsure how.

Comment: Hint:  do the terms go to $0$?

Comment: @James Dickens Are $n$ and $i$ the same stuff?

Comment: The partial sums give a non-constant periodic sequence, that obviously cannot be convergent.

Comment: Aside from lulu's very good hint, it might be worth knowing that this kind of sums can be computed: $$\sum_{k=0}^n\sin\frac{k\pi}{9}=\frac1{2i}\sum_{k=0}^ne^{ik\pi/9}-\frac1{2i} \sum_{k=0}^ne^{-ik\pi/9}=\\ =\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{1-e^{i\pi(n+1)/9}}{1-e^{i\pi/9}}-\frac{1-e^{-i\pi(n+1)/9}}{1-e^{-i\pi/9}}\right)$$ and so on.

Comment: It is convergent if $n = 9k$ and the series is REALLY $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sin\left(\frac {n \pi}{9}\right)...$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you remember learning about a test that gives you necessary, but not sufficient conditions for convergence? The test is called the [nth-term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test). Applying it here, we take the limit of your sequence and find that it does not exist. Therefore, your series diverges.

Comment: You are not taking the limit of the series, but rather the nth term of the series.

Comment: @zhw, sorry could you explain what you mean? I've always understood it as taking the limit of the series.

Comment: The $n$th term test states that if the sequence $a_n$ fails to converge to $0,$ then series $\sum a_n$ fails to converge.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I got series and sequence mixed up. I will edit my answer.